# iOS Static library for unity with App switching issue Facebook integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, plugins, unity-game-engine

These days i am writing a iOS static library for unity games facebook integration. Static library functionality is done and it works perfect. One issue i am facing is dont have any appdelegate inside my static library code so i cant add

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
        NSLog(@"openURL");
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Anywhere. This method needed to control app switching when app switch to get read or publish permissions. I created a demo project and added this method to the app delegate of demo project and it works Perfect but if i dont add this method to Appdelegate of demo project app switching does not happen. I dont want the plugin user to add this method manually after getting output from unity.

Is there any way to figure it out. So that app switching works perfect. Do i need add an appdelegate to static library classes or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `StaticLibAppDelegate` in your static library, implement the required functionality and ask the user of your library to inherit his `AppDelegate` from `StaticLibAppDelegate`.

`StaticLibAppDelegate` will inherit from `UIApplicationDelegate`. Ask the user to call `super` implementation from various delegate methods your library needs.

Ex: In his applications delegate, if user overrides `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` then ask him to call

```
[super application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
```

from his implementation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont need to do anything different inside this method. I just want to make sure that anyone who used this plugin dont need to add this "OpenURL method" in appdelegate after he/She gets output from unity. This method handle app switching for read and publish permissions.If this method is not added to appdelegate of demo or output from unity  switching doesnt happen. Even if i have added this method to my plugin class but that wont work and app just dont switch. Anyway ? Hope yu got me

Comment: You need to create Appdelegate class for your static library and ask user to inherit from that in his own application. This will ensure your library will get the call for required delegate function. Getting my point?

Comment: Great .! I have managed to do it somehow.. You gave me the clue to start with.. Thanks (y)

Comment: @amar can you please point me to a sample which helps a static lib to have her own ApplicationDelegate ?